Divide one Formula Numeric column by another in a Netsuite Saved Search
I am trying to divide the below formula by Quantity Available in a netsuite saved search.
CASE WHEN {transaction.type} = 'Sales Order' THEN {transaction.quantity}/8 ELSE 0 END

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.
I tried doing this in a formula numeric row. With sum selected and absolute value.
(SUM({quantityavailable}) / (CASE WHEN {transaction.type} = 'Sales Order' THEN {transaction.quantity}/8 ELSE, 0) END


What are your expected results?  What does the 8 represent?
